# 有効なTwitter URL かどうか、バリデーションチェックしたい

Tags: javascript, php, 正規表現, twitter

**現状**
ユーザが入力したツイートURLに基づき、(Twitter API で) ツイート 1件取得しています。
[リンク先](https://syncer.jp/Web/API/Twitter/REST_API/GET/statuses/show/id/)のベアラートークン使用しています

**やりたいこと**
ユーザが入力した段階で、有効なTwitter URL かどうか、バリデーションチェックしたい。
意図としては、無意味なURL入力されることを防ぎたいです。

---

**分からないこと**
有効なTwitter URL かどうか、どうやって判定？
リクエスト前の完全なバリデーションチェックは出来ない？？

- 案1.下記URL形式になっているかどうかで判定
  JavaScriptで正規表現使用？

  > https://twitter.com/xxxx/status/xxxx
- 案2.下記リクエスト後、HTTP レスポンスステータスコードが200かどうかで判定？
  PHP使用？

  > [GET statuses/show/:id](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-show-id.html)
- その他の案は何かありますか？

---

Comment: ホスト名からIPアドレスを取得することができますが、これは使えませんか？
https://webkaru.net/php/function-gethostbyname/

Comment: ホスト名からIPを取得することに意味はないかなと思います。なぜなら案1のURL形式にきちんと「twitter.com」というドメインで有ることを条件に加えれば問題ないと思います。

Comment: どこまで正確さを求めるか次第だと思います。単にtwitterドメインが含まれていればいいのか、ツイート自体が存在しているのかまで確認するのか。 / 参考: 英語版での関連質問 - [Validate twitter URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297253/validate-twitter-url)

Comment: @池田茂樹 今回の質問に限らず、一般にIPアドレスは固定されているものではない（規模が大きいWebサイトはDNSから大抵ロードバランサーを参照しているが、それも永続的なものではない）ので、IPアドレスを参照する手法は使えないかと存じます

Comment: 有効なURLかどうかのチェックですので、IPアドレスが取得できれば、それは存在するURLだと認識できると思ったのですが？

Comment: いずれにせよそれは「有効なドメイン」かのチェックにはつかえるかもしれませんが有効なツイートのURLかを判定したいという質問には不相応であるのは既存のコメントのとおりです。たとえば受け入れるべきドメインは `(mobile\.)?twitter\.com`とすればそのドメインが存在しているかたしかめるのは無駄でしょう。逆に極端な例とすれば`gethostname ('localhost')`は成功するでしょうし `gethostbyname('example.local')`は環境によっては(まあサーバーでmDNSが有効になっているのも考え難いかもしれませんが)解決できないがため無駄な時間がかかる場合があります。

Answer (score 1):

TwitterがAPI Specificationを公開しています。
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/labs/overview/introduction.html

PHP用のCodegenでクライアントを作成し、そのクライアントがパラメータを受け取れるか(例外を吐かないか)でバリデーションすることもできそうです。
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/samples/client/petstore/php/SwaggerClient-php

その他で、こういう手段もあるということで。