# Twitterの投稿URLにリクエストした際のレスポンスを判別する方法を教えてください

Tags: php, http, twitter, curl

#### 前提・実現したいこと

ひと月分の会員がつぶやいた投稿URLを抽出して
各投稿が有効性なのかを確かめたいです。
具体的には、

[https://twitter.com/アカウント名/status/投稿のID](https://twitter.com/%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AB%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E5%90%8D/status/%E6%8A%95%E7%A8%BF%E3%81%AEID)
が有効で投稿が表示されてるなら、２００番のOK

[https://twitter.com/アカウント名/status/投稿のID](https://twitter.com/%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AB%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E5%90%8D/status/%E6%8A%95%E7%A8%BF%E3%81%AEID)
が非公開アカウントであれば、３０２番のリダイレクト

[https://twitter.com/アカウント名/status/投稿のID](https://twitter.com/%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AB%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E5%90%8D/status/%E6%8A%95%E7%A8%BF%E3%81%AEID)
が見つからないであえば、４０４番のnot found

というような感じで判別したいです。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

- ひと月分の会員がつぶやいた投稿URLを抽出
  →こちらに関しては問題なくできています。
- 各投稿の有効性
  →４ヶ月ほど前は以前使用していた、チェックを行うphpファイルで判別できていましたが、
  現在Twitterの仕様が変わったのか、全て２００番で返ってきてしまいます。

#### 該当のソースコード

以前まではこの関数で取得し、判別できていました。

```php
   @get_headers();
```

#### 試したこと

- レスポンスヘッダー全てをチェックしてみる→特に有用な情報なし
- `get_headers` の引数を変えてみる→変化なし
- リダイレクト先URLを取得する方法をググってみる→`get_header` でできるらしいけど、
  たぶん200で返ってきてるからヘッダーにリダイレクト先URLが含まれない
- `curl -I` コマンドで投稿IDの部分を適当な文字列を入力→２００で返ってくる。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

他に必要な情報等ございましたら、言っていただけると助かります！

Comment: こちらの関連投稿も参考になるかもしれません: [有効なTwitter URL かどうか、バリデーションチェックしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/57018/32986)

Comment: 「Twitterの仕様が変わったのか」はい、最近大抵のリクエストへはSPAが返されるようになりました。APIを使ってください。がざっくりとは回答になるのですが、どうやらUAに`bot` の文字列を含めるとレスポンスが変わるとの話があります。（仕様変更でOGPのメタタグを取得できなくなった、という話から発覚しました）

Comment: "会員" は何を指していますか？文脈から察するに、質問中にあえて含める必要はなさそうに思いますが… / 「つぶやいた投稿URLを抽出」は実現できているなら "発生している問題" ではないですよね？

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/277920

Comment: @cubick 会員はつぶやきをすることでポイント獲得を目指しています。そのつぶやきが有効かを私たちは確認したいです。

Comment: @hinaloe APIを使えば実現可能ということでしょうか？

Comment: @hinaloe bot使用したらできました‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

> ４ヶ月ほど前は以前使用していた、チェックを行うphpファイルで判別できていましたが、
> 現在Twitterの仕様が変わったのか、全て２００番で返ってきてしまいます。

この点について、2020年初頭あたりから Twitter web の挙動が変わったのが関係しているはずです。

お行儀よく（つまり、Twitter のサーバーに必要以上の負荷をかけずに）状態を確認するためには、Twitter API の使用を検討してください。たとえばツイートの存在確認であれば GET statuses/show/:id や GET statuses/lookup が使えます:

- https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-show-id
- https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-lookup

ただし protected user かどうかは別途 API で判定する必要があります。

- https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-show

Comment: 今後、webの仕様がまた変わる可能性も高いのでAPIの方が影響を受けにくい、というのもありますね（尤もTwitterのAPIは近いうちに新しいバージョンがリリースされるかもしれませんが……）